# How long are Cognito Forms retained?

Tags: cognito-forms

How long does Cognito retain the forms? My workplace requires 3 years, would Cognito retain these forms for that long or do they get deleted after so long?

Answer (score 1):

Entries for active organizations are maintained in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) forever as long as you do not delete them.  We do not retain copies of deleted entries for privacy reasons.

The only exception is that, per the [Terms of Service](https://www.cognitoforms.com/terms):

> We reserve the right to terminate any free Accounts that have no
>   activity for 6 months.